# Why is my django web-app login form not working?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I've tried to add login form to my tasks web-app, but something goes wrong and I can't login to my created admin user. After click on the login button page just clearing up and my url changes to [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMYDo.png). I have no idea how to fix it, help me please.

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', TaskList.as_view(), name='tasks'),
    path('login/', CustomLoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('logout/', LogoutView.as_view(next_page='login'), name='logout'),
    path('task/<int:pk>', TaskDetail.as_view(), name='task'),
    path('task-create/', TaskCreate.as_view(), name='task-create'),
    path('task-edit/<int:pk>', TaskUpdate.as_view(), name='task-edit'),
     path('task-delete/<int:pk>', TaskDelete.as_view(), name='task-delete'),

]
```

**views.py**

```
class CustomLoginView(LoginView):
    template_name = 'base/login.html'
    fields = '__all__'
    redirect_authenticated_user = True

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('tasks')
```

**login.html**

```
<h1>Login</h1>
<form metrhod="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it possibly be a spelling error? `metrhod="POST"`

Try this:

```py
<h1>Login</h1>
<form method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot, I've just missed it!